# mysql select query ignoring inner spaces

Tags: mysql

Banging me head against the wall with this one.

I have table containing postcodes and street names and I have another table where Houses are listed for sale ( where the Street name is missing)  and I am tryin to get the Street name for each post code.

The problem is that table 1 stores the postcode without the space and table 2 which I am trying to update stores the post code with the space.

So in table 1 the postcode is stored as "l249pb" and table 2 it is stored as "l24 9pb".

Now if the post codes where both stored in exactly the same format i.e without the space I would expect this query to work:

```
UPDATE Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON ( Table1.PostCode = Table2.PostCode )
SET Table1.StreetName = Table2.StreetName
```

I have tried this but it wont work :

```
UPDATE Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON ( Table1.PostCode = REPLACE(Table2.PostCode,' ',''))
SET Table1.StreetName = Table2.StreetName
```

can anyone tell me how to check for a match ignoring spaces ( like a trim but removing every space )

Many thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Opps thanks for pointing that out, I have now edited it

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S you can use function in join expression as well, so the solution in the OP could work.

Comment: 1) Determine if those are truly spaces between the the 2 parts of the post code and not a tab or line break, or sg similar that may appear as a space (use a select query to see the effects of replace) 2) Check if the letter case in the 2 fields is the same.

Comment: To perform a case insensitive comparison, you can use `UPPER(Table1.PostCode) = UPPER(REPLACE(Table2.PostCode,' ',''))`, (or `LOWER`of course). To deal with the whitespaces I don't know any mysql buit-in function.

Answer (score 0):

With the data you've given your `UPDATE` runs just fine. Probably the whitespaces you see are not actually spaces, but [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character), e.g. non-breaking spaces, tabs etc.

After normal `SPACE`, the next most common white spaces (which are not line breaks) are `CHARACTER TABULATION` (ie. horizontal tab) and `NO-BREAK SPACE`. You could use `CHAR(9)` and `CHAR(160)`, respectively, to reference them in your query.

It also might be possible that your table viewer application shows line breaks as a space for brevity, so if replacing space, tab and nbsp isn't enough, try replacing those, too.

If you *really* need to replace all white space characters… Unfortunately there is no "white space wildcard" to use in MySQL. Technically, you could make a monster `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE…`-call, which, in the end, would replace all whitespace characters with `''`. For example, to replace every `THREE-PER-EM SPACE`, first look for its Unicode code point (`U+2004`), then you can replace its occurences e.g. with:
 `REPLACE(PostCode, CHAR(0x2004 using ucs2), '')`

There is a hackish shortcut to this: if you are sure that your data should contain only Latin-1 characters and no `?` (question mark), you could `CONVERT()` the string first as latin1, which replaces all characters with overflowing code as `?`and then replace all `?` as `''`:
`REPLACE(CONVERT(PostCode using latin1), '?', '')`
This can be useful in one-off, manual queries, but for continuing use, better replace the characters explicitly.

---

**But first** you should check your data input sanitizer/validator, so future records won't be such a mess. Perhaps you could consider running a bulk replace to normalize the data on `PostCode` column(s), if possible, before even trying to do your join query. Legacy systems with legacy data only [get worse over time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).